# How to insert multiple values into different rows using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table MG_DEVICE_GROUP_IN_GEOZONE that has two columns

```
| deviceGroup_id| geozone_id|
| ------------- | --------- |
```

I want to insert multiple values to both columns:

- in geozone_id should be all ids from nested query
- in deviceGroup_id should be one value for all - 4525

I'm tried to use this query:

```
insert into MG_DEVICE_GROUP_IN_GEOZONE (deviceGroup_id, geozone_id)
values (4525, (select id from MG_GEOZONE where account_id = 114 and zoneType in (0, 1 , 3)));
```

But I receiving error - "[21000][1242] Subquery returns more than 1 row"

I understand why this error appeared but I can't find the right query to do this. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
insert into MG_DEVICE_GROUP_IN_GEOZONE (deviceGroup_id, geozone_id)
select 4525,id from MG_GEOZONE where account_id = 114 and zoneType in (0, 1 , 3);
```

The [INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) statement can be followed by a SELECT statement, which produces the values to be inserted.